# How to send Notes with formatting to a remote iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sharing, notes.app

I made a note on my iPhone with formatting. How can I send this to another iPhone user and preserve the formatting? AirDrop is not possible because they are not nearby.

I tried saving the note to Files and then sending the file, but turns out that saving a note to Files actually only saves the note's plaintext without any formatting (not even tabs for indentation).

Sharing via Messages, which I expected to work because iMessage is Apple tech, also only copies the note's plaintext into the messaging box.